# Adding Years to a random date from Date class

Tags: java

Let's say I have this:

```
 PrintStream out = System.out;
 Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
 out.print("Enter a number ... ");
 int n = in.nextInt();
```

I have a random date, for example, 05/06/2015 (it is not a fixed date, it is random every time). If I want to take the 'year' of the this date, and add whatever 'n' is to this year, how do i do that?

None of the methods in the Date Class are 'int'.

And to add years from an int, 'years' has to be an int as well.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You need to convert the `Date` to a `Calendar`.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(randomDate);
c.add(Calendar.YEAR, n);
newDate = c.getTime();
```

You can manipulate the Year (or other fields) as a Calendar, then convert it back to a Date.

Comment: what if my date is SimpleDateFormat class? for c.setTime(randomDate); what do i do?

Comment: @user1519192 Whenever you get a String that you want to parse into a Date, you can the `parse()` method of your `SimpleDateFormat`. A SimpleDateFormat is not a date, it is a definition of a format that a Date can represent and is used to convert a `Date` to a `String` and vice versa.

Answer (score 21):

This question has long deserved a modern answer. And even more so after [Add 10 years to current date in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47206400/add-10-years-to-current-date-in-java-8) has been deemed a duplicate of this question.

The other answers were fine answers in 2012. The years have moved on, today I believe that no one should use the now outdated classes `Calendar` and `Date`, not to mention `SimpleDateFormat`. The modern Java date and time API is so much nicer to work with.

Using the example from [that duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47206400/add-10-years-to-current-date-in-java-8), first we need

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter formatter 
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

With this we can do:

```
    String currentDateString = "2017-09-12 00:00:00";
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(currentDateString, formatter);
    dateTime = dateTime.plusYears(10);
    String tenYearsAfterString = dateTime.format(formatter);
    System.out.println(tenYearsAfterString);
```

This prints:

```
2027-09-12 00:00:00
```

If you don’t need the time of day, I recommend the `LocalDate` class instead of `LocalDateTime` since it is exactly a date without time of day.

```
    LocalDate date = dateTime.toLocalDate();
    date = date.plusYears(10);
```

The result is a date of `2027-09-12`.

**Question: where can I learn to use the modern API?**

You may start with the [Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). There’s much more material on the net, go search.

Answer (score 9):

Another package for doing this exists in `org.apache.commons.lang3.time`, `DateUtils`.

```
Date date = new Date();
date = DateUtils.addYears(date, int quantity = 1);
```

Answer (score 5):

The `Date` class will not help you, but the `Calendar` class can:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Date f;
...
cal.setTime(f);
cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, n); // Where n is int
f = cal.getTime();
```

Notice that you still have to assign a value to the `f` variable. I frequently use `SimpleDateFormat` to convert strings to dates.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Try `java.util.Calendar` type.

```
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(yourDate.getTime());
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,n);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will add 3 years to the current date and print the year.

```
 System.out.println(LocalDate.now().plusYears(3).getYear());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need add one year a any date use the object Calendar.

```
Calendar dateMoreOneYear = Calendar.getInstance();
dateMoreOneYear.setTime(dateOriginal);
dateMoreOneYear.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 365);
```

Comment: Really bad idea, this doesn't account for leap years (366 days).

Answer (score 0):

Try like this as well for a just month and year like (June 2019)

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, n); //here n is no.of year you want to increase
SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM YYYY");
System.out.println(cal.getTime());

String formatted = format1.format(cal.getTime());
System.out.println(formatted);
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this....

```
String s = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY").format(new Date(random_date_in_long)); // 
int i = Integer.parseInt(s)+n;
```

Comment: Fails for cases like leap year